# Display Unique Shell Columns

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, zsh

Given we have two formatted strings that are unrelated to each other.
    #test.rb
    string_1 = "Title\nfoo bar\nbaz\nfoo bar baz boo"
    string_2 = "Unrelated Title\ndog cat farm\nspace moon"

How can I use ruby or call shell commands to have each of these string display as columns in terminal?  The key is that the data of each string are not building a correlated row, ie this is not a table, rather 2 lists side by side.

```
Title            Unrelated Title
foo bar          dog cat farm
baz              space moon
foo bar baz boo
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using paste and column command together. Note that this is a shell command so spaces between the assignment operator should be corrected.

```
$ string_1="Title\nfoo bar\nbaz\nfoo bar baz boo"
$ string_2="Unrelated Title\ndog cat farm\nspace moon"
$ paste -d '|' <(echo -e "$string_1") <(echo -e "$string_2") | column -s'|' -t
Title            Unrelated Title
foo bar          dog cat farm
baz              space moon
foo bar baz boo
```

We paste the lines with `|` as delimiter and tell column command to use `|` as a reference to form columns.

Comment: What would you do if string_1 and string_2 where within test.rb?

Comment: I would go with ruby. This was just a mean to demonstrate using shell commands. I dont see any point of using them inside Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, you could do it this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

string_1 = "Title\nfoo bar\nbaz\nfoo bar baz boo"
string_2 = "Unrelated Title\ndog cat farm\nspace moon"

a1 = string_1.split("\n")
a2 = string_2.split("\n")

a1.zip(a2).each { |pair| puts "%-20s%s" % [pair.first, pair.last] }
# or
# a1.zip(a2).each { |left, right| puts "%-20s%s" % [left, right] }
```

This produces:

```
Title               Unrelated Title
foo bar             dog cat farm
baz                 space moon
foo bar baz boo
```

Answer (score 0):

## Hi , If you Use temp files

```
string_1 = "Title\nfoo bar\nbaz\nfoo bar baz boo"
string_2 = "Unrelated Title\ndog cat farm\nspace moon"
echo -e $string_1 >a.txt
echo -e $string_2 >b.txt
paste a.txt b.txt
```

## I hope it will help.